# how connect to lightstreamer with python?

Tags: python, lightstreamer

i want to connect to lightstramer with python

[lightstreamer example](https://demos.lightstreamer.com/MPNStockListDemo_Basic/)

i try

```
import asyncio
import websockets as websockets

header = {
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,fa;q=0.8',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Connection': 'Upgrade',
    'Host': 'push.lightstreamer.com',
    'Origin': 'https://demos.lightstreamer.com',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Sec-WebSocket-Extensions': 'permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits',
    'Sec-WebSocket-Key': '0JsNTUnSx4IOsbmuLusyaw==',
    'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol': 'TLCP-2.1.0.lightstreamer.com',
    'Sec-WebSocket-Version': '13',
    'Upgrade': 'websocket',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 '
                  'Safari/537.36',
}

async def hello():
async with websockets.connect('wss://push.lightstreamer.com/lightstreamer', extra_headers=header) as websocket:
        greeting = await websocket.recv()
        print(greeting)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())
```

but always get error

```
websockets.exceptions.InvalidStatusCode: server rejected WebSocket connection: HTTP 400
```

how can i connect to this and get data??what library i need?

Comment: Did you check https://github.com/Lightstreamer?q=python ?

Comment: yes.some of gits is for server and i cant understand nothing from others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, Lightstreamer does not offer an official python client library, but you could leverage this simple [example](https://github.com/Lightstreamer/Lightstreamer-example-StockList-client-python), which uses *HTTP Streaming* for communicating with a Lightstreamer server instance.

Moreover, have a look at the [TLCP Specifications](https://lightstreamer.com/docs/client_TLCP_base/TLCP%20Specifications.pdf) for more details about how to implement the communication protocol.

Comment: i solve it,using this example and change it to my lightstreamer.u need to change some of funcations and basic codes of this example Including _control ,connect and BIND_URL_PATH,CONNECTION_URL_PATH and ...
but it worked and no need to websocket
thank Gianluca